# Remove whitespace around certain character with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, whitespace

I have a string where I want to remove all the whitespace around a certain character using **preg_replace**. In my case this character is `/`.

For example:

`first part / second part` would become `first part/second part`

Or let's say that character is `:` now:

`first part : second part` would become `first part:second part`

I couldn't find an example on how to do this... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys, you were fast!
All of the solutions work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow creatoro! We try to be very fast on most questions here - it's even a good idea to refresh the page after a few minutes to see all the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace("/\s*([\/:])\s*/", "$1", $string);
```

Explanation:

- `\s*` means any amount (`*`) of whitespace (`\s`)
- `[\/:]` is either a `/` or a `:`. If you want another character, just add it here.
- the brackets are a capture group which you reference with the `$1` meaning that if it matches a `:` then the $1 will mean `:`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `:` with your character.

```
$string = preg_replace("/\s*:\s*/", ":", $string);
```

In english:

Replace **any amount of whitespace (including 0)**, then a `:` and then any amount of whitespace again, by just a `:`.

Answer (score 1):

match optional space followed by your character (captured in brackets) followed by another optional space and then replace by your captured character

`preg_replace('/\s*(:)\s*/',"$1",$str);`