# Javascript Regex: How to remove all whitespaces around certain character?

Tags: javascript, regex

Probably I am doing something wrong, I found a regex to achieve the needed replacement in [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551637/remove-whitespace-around-certain-character-with-preg-replace) and in [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536195/regex-to-remove-unwanted-spaces-around-certain-characters), but applying it to javascript fails.

Example:

`text ( 4 |-4 | 1 "test"  )  [ 0 50 90 ]`

Should get cleaned to:

`text(4|-4|1 "test")[0 50 90]`

As you see, I remove all whitespaces before and after the brackets and the |.

My code so far:

```
        // remove whitespaces around brackets []
        text = text.replace(/\s*\[\s*(.*?)\s*]\s*/g, '[$1]');
        // remove whitespaces around brackets ()
        text = text.replace(/\s*\(\s*(.*?)\s*\)\s*/g, '($1)');
        // remove all whitespaces around | (FAILS)
        // text = text.replace(/\s*\|\s*(.*?)\s*\|\s*/g, '|$1|');
        // text = text.replace(/\s*|\s*/, '$1');
```

Looks also too complicated.

I would like to know the regex for each sign.

Not all replacements in one regex, for learning I would prefer one replacement per line.

Comment: You can try [`[ ]*([\][(|)])[ ]*`](https://regex101.com/r/kU2tZ2/2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```js
var text = 'text ( 4 |-4 | 1 "test"  )  [ 0 50 90 ]';
text = text.replace(/\s*([|()[\]])\s*/g, '$1');

alert(text)
```

This regex looks for (optional) whitespace, then, in a capature group, one of the characters that can't have bordering spaces, then another optional whitespace, and replaces all that with just the character, effectively removing the whitespace.

---

Now, if you want to place the replacements on seperate lines, and only replace space characters, leaving other whitespace intact, try this:

```js
var text = 'text ( 4 |-4 | 1 "test"  )  [ 0 50 90 ]';
text = text.replace(/ *([|]) */g, '$1')
           .replace(/ *([(]) */g, '$1')
           .replace(/ *([)]) */g, '$1')
           .replace(/ *([[]) */g, '$1')
           .replace(/ *([\]]) */g, '$1');

alert(text)
```

Or this:

```js
var text = 'text ( 4 |-4 | 1 "test"  )  [ 0 50 90 ]';
text = text.replace(/ *(|) */g, '$1')
           .replace(/ *(\() */g, '$1')
           .replace(/ *(\)) */g, '$1')
           .replace(/ *(\[) */g, '$1')
           .replace(/ *(\]) */g, '$1');

alert(text)
```

For single characters, character classes are a bit overkill, but you'll need to escape `()[]`, then. (Like I did in the last snippet)

Comment: You don't need to escape '['.

Comment: Thanks, but what would it be per character (not all in one). So one code line per replacement?

Comment: Furthermore I just realize that it removes linebreaks. Why that?

Comment: That's because `\s` means "all" whitespace, I'll update my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to correctly escape the reserved chars, so a single `[` becomes a `\[` and so on. The pipe is also a reserved character, so you'll need to do the same:

```js
var example = "text ( 4 |-4 | 1 \"test\"  )  [ 0 50 90 ]";
    example = example.replace(/\s*([\(\)])\s*/g, '$1')); // removes the ()
    example = example.replace(/\s*([\[\]])\s*/g, '$1')); // removes the []
    example = example.replace(/\s*([\|])\s*/g, '$1'));   // removes the |

    // or remove all characters at once
    example = example.replace(/\s*([\(\)\[\]\|])\s*/g, '$1')

alert(example)
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `|`, `[` or `()` in regex char classes.

Comment: I do agree with you @Cerbrus, but seems easier to remember to always escape special characters and escaping them doesn't hurt.